# How make my architecture scalable to handle linear process

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I have a system to calculate Real Time Traffic (RTT), using Automatic Vehicle Location (**[AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vehicle_location)**).

I can know where the car was, where is now, and calculating distance and time can estimate the traffic speed on those roads. I have two store procedures:

- `near_link` using avl `(x,y)` found the near road link
- `create_route` using pgrouting extension, current link and previous link can calculate the route the vehicule took.

Both process are very linear, calculate the `near_link` for 1 row take 10 ms, calculate for 100 rows take 1000 ms or 1 sec. calculate the route is a litle more expensive 50 ms for one route or 5 sec for 100 routes.

The problem is the avl fleet growth, so instead of 400 avl/min I now receive 2000 avl/min. And instead of `400*60ms = 24 sec` now I need `2000*60 = 120 sec`, so every minute I can only process half of the data.

The only solution I can think right now is have two separated servers one handle even car_id and the other odd car_id so split the load between both servers.

Currently Im using just a production Desktop, Windows i3 Core 3Ghz 8gb RAM normal disks. I can request a better hardware for the production server. For example I know the querys are very HDD demanding because need to check the map_rto table very often, but I can see in the resources monitor CPU and Memory very low use. So I could upgrade to SDD disk. And hope my time is reduce to half.

But what happen when the fleet increase to 4000 avl/min or to 8000 avl/min. **What are the strategies to scale those linear calculations??.**

---

Aditional description of current design:

I like the idea of use of pgAgent and triggers to move the data from one stage to another. But maybe there is a better way to do it.

[image]

- **avl_sources (table):** I can have multiple companies providing data and each one has a separated table and there are triggers on each table to insert new rows into the `avl_pool` table

  - Each row has: `car_id`, `x`, `y`, `azimuth`, `datetime`.
  - I check external source every min, receive around 2000 records and take ~5 sec to finish all the process.
- **map_rto (table):** contain my coutry roads information. There are ~3 million links. Is used to calculate the `near_link` and the `route`
- **near_link (sp):**  Using avl `x, y, azimuth` try to find the closest link to that position. I call this sp from a pg_agent job every minute.
- **export (sp):** Also call this sp from pgAgent. Move those avl with near_link to `traffic_avl` table
- **traffic_avl (table):**: This table has a trigger to using the current position and previous position calculate the route.

Comment: I think at some point you will need to `partition` your problem into parallel servers, and probably use some infrastructure specifically thought for parallel processing (such as [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/streaming/)). The kind of problem you're dealing with suggests that a geographic partinioning strategy (one server receives data for vehicles within a certain geographical zone) might be a good one. This goes beyond databases, and into a (probably) big data approach (high volume, high velocity).

Comment: How big will the fleet be in the foreseeable future?  Also, what are the current PostgreSQL memory settings?  `shared_buffers`, `work_mem` and so on?

Comment: the fleet is 16000 cars, but that is different to the avl data generated for each  cars, I get around 2000 avl rows/minute. I expect that will double in the near future, and double again later. shared_buffers and work_mem both are 1800MB. But again the problem isnt the function performance. (10 ms and 60 ms) the problem is when more rows arrive can be process on the time window.

Comment: Isn't the performance of the functions the thing which is preventing them from fitting the data into the time window?  If so, why do you say that is not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you suspect the disk is the limiting factor, upgrading to SSD sounds like your best option if you are focused on hardware.  More RAM might also work, if it would allow to cache most of the slow table/indices.  (How big is map_rto and its most-used index)?

If you would rather try tuning the hardware you already have, or making sure that that is really the issue before buy hardware, then you should identify the slow queries from your stored procedures, and follow [this advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) for them.

Particularly useful would be turn on track_io_timing and post the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the slow queries.

Finally, is the code that calls these two functions single-threaded?  If so, you could try making it parallel, with different database connections for each thread.